# Tag badges got refreshed just for me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges

I only have two bronze tag badges, which were earned long ago. But a couple of minutes ago, I just received a notification stating that I just earned these badges.

[zelda-skyward-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-skyward-sword) https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/233/zelda-skyward-sword
[image: Earned Zelda Skyward Sword Tag badge]

[assassins-creed-revelations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-revelations) https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/395/assassins-creed-revelations
[image: Earned Assassin's Creed Revelations Tag Badge]

Even shows as earned a few minutes ago.

What happened? I was proud to have been the first to have earned these badges.

Comment: Did this happen to anyone else?

Comment: [This meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11364/re-earned-all-my-tag-badges-at-once) from RPG appears to be related. Seems like a really weird bug to me.

Comment: It's happening across the network, so I've posted a [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/295232) on the main Meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be resolved. Lots more details on what happened and why are available [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/164200).

Comment: By resolved, are you saying that this shouldn't happen anymore? Will the changes that were made be reverted as well (timestamps)?

Comment: As mentioned in the linked post, the change that resulted in the issue were reverted. I'm working on a fix to restore the timestamps to badge awards.